# How to count the occurrence of specific string on a specific line in a file?

Tags: command-line, wc

I know I can use wc to return the total number of words (and lines) in a file using:

```
wc <filename>
```

Is there a way to return the count for a specific string on a specific line of a file like the following:

```
wc <filename> -<flag> <line number> -<flag> <string>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This needs to be done in three steps:

1. Select line number N (example uses line 42):

   ```
   sed '42!d'
   ```
2. Search the line for all occurrences of a specific pattern (here the string/regular expression `hello`) and print those separately:

   ```
   grep -o 'hello'
   ```
3. Count the matches:

   ```
   wc -l
   ```

Or to put it in one single command pipe, reading from `file.txt`:

```
sed '42!d' file.txt | grep -o 'hello' | wc -l
```

Comment: grep has a count mode, the wc is not needed

Comment: @hildred grep's `-c` counts matching *lines* - not much use to get the number of matching strings in a single line

Comment: Actually if you split that line with sed into multiple lines then grep -c can be used with no problems

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but then you'd be going out of your way to make something contrived. Unix philosophy is for programs to be focused and composable. `grep` is for searching, and `wc` is for counting. Composing them is more natural, and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @jlmg there's nothing particularly contrived about such approach. Taking out a line and splitting it into multiple lines doesn't go against Unix philosophy in any way. `sed` does its job, `grep` does its job, and we merely string them together. See my asnwer, I added this as a solution

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy What I meant was going against Unix philosophy was `grep`'s `-c` option which causes `grep` to count rather than influence its searching. What I found contrived was splitting the line simply to use a feature that went against `grep`'s focus and avoid a composition with `wc` whose sole job is counting. Anyway, this is just splitting hairs; I'm not saying your solution isn't also valid.

Answer (score 8):

This is a good use case for putting Unix tools together in a pipeline.

```
line=5
str="ipsum"
sed -n "${line}p" filename | grep -o -- "$str" | wc -l
```

The sed `p` command outputs the given line of the file, and feeds it into grep. Grep's `-o` option tells it to output all the matches for the given string, and each match is output on a separate line. Grep's output is fed to wc, which counts the number of lines.

Answer (score 7):

#### Python

Here's one way to do it in **Python** via list comprehension (see below for alternative shorter version).

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print([ l for i,l in enumerate(sys.stdin,1) if i==2][0].count("word"))' < input.txt                                          
3
$ cat input.txt
nothing here
word and another word, and one more word
last line
```

How this works:

- we run python interpreter with `-c` flag, were commands are contained within single quotes;
- the input file `input.txt` is redirected into `stdin` stream of the python interpreter via `<` shell operator. Hence we need `sys` module.
- Using list comprehension structure `[something for item in something]`, we read lines of text from `sys.stdin`.
- `enumerate(sys.stdin,1)` allows us to count enumerate the lines, i.e. with each iteration of list comprehension, we'll get the line of text into `l` variable and index into `i` variable starting the count at 1.
- The `i==2` will filter out only line which index equals to 2. That's how we know which line to extract.
- Thus as a result our list will contain only one item, and within the list its index is `0`. So, we refer to that item as `[<list comprehension stuff here>][0]`. 
  -The `.count("word")` is what actually does the job of counting. By definition it returns a number of non-overlapping  occurrences of a substring in a string.
- finally all of that stuff was contained within `print()` statement. So whatever number the `.count()` method returns will show up on screen.

#### Shorter version

The shorter way to do the same in Python would be to use `readlines()` method instead of list comprehension, and refer to specific item in the list that `readlines()` produces. Note, that `readlines()` produces a list, and lists in Python are 0-indexed, which means if you want to read line x, you should reference list item x-1. For instance,

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.stdin.readlines()[1].count("word"))' < input.txt       
3
```

#### sed+grep

Of course, we don't have to stick with scripting languages alone. `sed` and `grep` provide sufficient tools which we can use to suit our needs. With `grep -c` we can count occurrence of matched lines, so all we have to do is extract the specific line we need, and split all words in that line into separate lines. Like so:

```
$ sed -n  '2{s/ /\n/g;p}' input.txt | grep -c 'word'
3
```

Comment: Why do you read from `sys.stdin` instead of just opening the file in Python using `open("input.txt")`?

Comment: @ByteCommander  no particular reason. That can be done,too. Although `open()` makes the line a little longer.  There's no particular advantage either way,though

Comment: `python -c 'n,w,f=2,"word",open("input.txt");[f.readline()for _ in range(n-1)];print(f.readline().count(w))'` would be my personal suggestion.

Comment: @ByteCommander to your first comment: Probably because not calling the `close` method on the result of `open` is a memory leak?

Comment: @cat as far as i know, Python interpreter will close things automatically if you use the -c flag. Its a common hack for golfing in Python

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Of course, handles are closed when the program exits, it's just that handle leaks from the time it is opened until the program ends, which may be quite some CPU time depending on the size of the file

Comment: BTW, this only works if the searched string does not contain spaces. In this way, the `wc` solution worked better.

Comment: @jlmg the Python one will work with spaces, sed + grep one won't, agreed there

Answer (score 6):

`awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==X { print gsub("word",""); }' file
```

- change the `X` with your specific line number.
- change the "word" with your desired word.
- `gsub` returns number of replacement of the "word", looks like we are counting it.

---

Exampe:

```
$ cat file:
a b c a a d
d e f f f 1
```

let's see how many 'f' we got in line "2":

```
$ awk 'NR==2 { print gsub("f",""); }' file
3
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it, in `perl`:

```
perl -lne '
  BEGIN{($lineno, $str) = splice @ARGV,0,2} 
  print $c = () = /$str/g if $. == $lineno
' <lineno> <string> <filename>
```